# why dose events trigger for child element when chlid not defind with the events but parent has events defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a image enclosed inside div. And i defined mouseover and mouseout events for parent.

```
<div id="leftnav" ng-mouseover="leftnavOver($event)" ng-mouseout="leftnavOut($event)" ng-mouseleave="leftnavOut($event)"><img width="20" src="images/left-arrow.png"></div>
```

angular code

```
$scope.leftnavOver = function ($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).css("background", "red")
}

$scope.leftnavOut = function ($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).css("background", "black")
}
```

why does events gets triggered for both div and img....

Answer (score 2):

The `mouseover/out` event fires on the child and bubbles up. You can detect the source of the event by comparing `$event.target` with the source element. `$event.target` is the element that spawned the event (the `img`).

You can also use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead which [does not bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter).

Comment: $event.srcElement works only with ie. I used another method to solve it $event.currentTarget

Comment: Oh right, yea, sorry. You can keep a reference to the source element. You can do this fairly easy if wrap all event handlers. Maybe angular even has a function or property for it?

Answer (score 0):

Because `img` is part of `div`. And event is bound on `div`.

To stop this, you can use `stopPropagation` as follow:

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftnav" ng-mouseover="leftnavOver($event)" ng-mouseout="leftnavOut($event)" ng-mouseleave="leftnavOut($event)">
    <img width="20" src="images/left-arrow.png" ng-mouseover="imgEvents()" ng-mouseout="imgEvents()" ng-mouseleave="imgEvents()" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.imgEvents = function ($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).stopPropagation();
};
```